# IntelliJ is running old class files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij for my project development(Java). Strangely, whenever I try to run the project making some new changes to it, Intellij is always running old class files which were complied for a older version of my project. I tried recompiling, rebuilding, tried invalidate caches and restart, removed the project and opened it again but nothing seems to work. Not able to figure out the reason and now I am clueless what to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you changed the module settings? Make sure it's not including an old jar.

Comment: try deleting build folder(s) manually.

Comment: How can I do that? @Compass

Comment: I tried deleting all the .class files in the bin directory but that didn't work either. It's still picking up old class files. @NabinBhandari

Comment: Make sure they are cleaned properly. There is no way of deleted files being recovered and used automatically. 
Last Resort: Create new project or reinstall intelliJ

Comment: Are you using a development framework, for example Maven, or is all handcrafted?

Comment: No, I am not using any development framework. @AdrianM.

Comment: I just deleted `build` and `out` folders.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same issue and I haven't been able to consistently make it go away, however, here's some things I've tried that could help:

- delete .class files
- invalidate caches and restart
- check settings: sdk and source path imports of IDEA code might affect it
- delete and reinstall intellij

Or do what I've ultimately done, which is to create a new project and avoid spending 5 hours tinkering with IntelliJ to get it to run my code properly.

Comment: I just imported the project to eclipse. It gave the the same problem as IntelliJ but I fiddled with some settings and it started working again. It is now working in IntelliJ as well. Not sure what caused the problem and what solved it either. @Rowan

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to let IntelliJ "forget" all old internal files:

1. Close the running IntelliJ instance.
2. Delete the `.idea` directory of your project.
3. Open the project like a new project.

After that you have a fresh IntelliJ project that probably needs some configuration (as usual).

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem in IntelliJ by a maven enabled project.
Running maven clean phase and ... , but no effect,
any change to classes had no effect in deployed project. 
finally I found the problem. 
classes was hidden in this path: 
{Project Path}\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes{my packages}
by removing this, problems has gone.

Hope it was useful.

Comment: Thank you for posting, i realized this is a good place to see what .class files are in the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the maven issue within Intellij settings. When I used bundled version it gave the error it should have. I don't know why giving actual path won't work but Bundled Version will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of [Java Parser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser), I needed to run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` after each change on the command line. Then, class changes were available in IntelliJ. No other way helped here.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean` fixed it for me.

In my case I ran all tests in a package and a deleted test class was included in the test. After `mvn clean` the deleted class doesn't appear any more.